# Two question about effective mass?

Tags: mass, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I have two questions about this slide.
1. Is the <100> direction in k-space corresponding to the momentum  in the (100) plane of the crystal ?
2. Could you explain the every data of effective mass in insert window to me in detail ? why _⊥ = 0.916 ? and what is the meaning of Subscript ⊥？...
Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Hi omop, have you figured out the first question? I have the same confusion right now. I guess the answer is yes for the first question.